# Can someone identify this species of Protolophus?

Tags: species-identification

I have posted my observation on iNaturalist, but so far this Harvestman has only been identified as genus, Protolophus. Here are three angles of the Harvestman in question, which has been observed in North Sacramento County, California.[image]